# Determine the tangents of angles A and B.

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Q.  Use the triangle in Figure 6-1 to determine the tangents of angles A and B.

Comment: if the triangle is $45º,90º$ then $\tan (A)$ should be $1$. Aren't you missing something?

Comment: The answer to the problem is above. I just don't get where the four comes from?

Comment: I think you are looking to different problems.

Comment: No, I am not. I need to understand, why the 4 is part of the equation?

Comment: why do you think that the angles are $45º, 90º$?

Comment: I'm just judging by eyesight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50097/discussion-between-arnaldo-nascimento-and-william-zlacki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice remark. The explanation is given because of the equality $a=b$ in whose case one clearly has
$$\frac ab=\frac ba=1$$

Comment: Where does the four come from?

Comment: I don't understand what the rol of $4$ is. You always have for arbitrary $x$ that $x=\dfrac{4x}{4}$. I am going delette my answer? Regards.

Comment: Now I'm confused.

Comment: Solve it now???

Comment: What applies to $4x$?

Comment: I'm so sorry, my dear friend. I do not understand what you mean and neither does my answer that I do not remember doing